# Mirroring an Android display via Android Studio

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen, external-display

I have an Android (first-generation Pixel) with a broken display. While the display does still appear to receive touch events, its ability to actually display anything seems to be basically done for.

Before I get a replacement phone (which I will, in a few days), I was wondering whether I could mirror the display on a laptop via some of Android Studio's visual or command-line tools, or otherwise without installing third party apps.

Is this possible at all, considering how limited my interaction with the display is?

Comment: How about https://www.vysor.io app? Also if you're able to connect phone to debugging, you can do screenshots in Android Studio so that you can somehow navigate where you want.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; Yes because it receives touch events.

Why?  I have even done this with the original iPhone 2G back with a jailbreak.  Basically I would copy the configuration files from a working jailbroken iPhone onto the broken iPhone.   Back then I used Chickenvnc and a VNC root application.  The problem with Android is that I do not know of a current VNC application that let's you operate the entire device from VNC even with *root*.  There are literally zero to my knowledge.  My question here has gone unanswered for similar reasons.  [Home Screen Launcher Completely Operated By Keyboard & Alpha VNC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181551/home-screen-launcher-completely-operated-by-keyboard-alpha-vnc)  But you have touch events so you should be able to configure the device on an identical pixel and then flash the exact same configuration onto the broken pixel.  The tricky part will be navigating the home screen.